# How can I minus both x and y position of some image that is taken with pyautogui?

Tags: python, screenshot, pyautogui

I'm basically trying to click little down of recognized image that was taken by pyautogui.locateOnScreen. To be able to do that I need to get the first position that I can easily get with locateOnScreen and then I need to decrease both x and y value of itself to fulfil my need , can anyone help?

I can't make it work basically , I need to be able to do the calculations and make it click there.

Comment: How about `pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen("foo.png"))`

Comment: how can this help?

Comment: This will give you the x and y coordinates of the center of that image which is what I assume you are after based on _"need to decrease both x and y value of itself"_ and _"I need to be able to do the calculations and make it click there"_ Is that not what you want to do?

Comment: I needed to modify "top" array of an coordinate. I figured it out.

Comment: editedPos=Pos[0],Pos[1]+15,Pos[2],Pos[3]